# Shell script query for MongoDB using AND/OR

Tags: bash, mongodb, shell, mongodb-query

I have a shell script with a query to get some information in a `MongoDB` database and I'm having a problem to make a more detailed query.

For example, if the query is simple it works, like this:

```
exec_mongo='mongo -u USER HOST/MYDATABASE -pPASSWORD --authenticationDatabase admin'

query='printjson(db.MYDATABASE.find().toArray())'

res=$($exec_mongo --eval $query)

echo $res >> results.csv
```

But, if I add some parameters, like "AND" or "OR", doesn't work:

```
exec_mongo='mongo -u USER HOST/MYDATABASE -pPASSWORD --authenticationDatabase admin'

query='printjson(db.MYDATABASE.find($and: [ {DATE:"2018"}, {NAME:"TEST"} ]).toArray())'

res=$($exec_mongo --eval $query)

echo $res >> results.csv
```

I think maybe this is because of the `$and`, but not sure about. Can anyone help me with this, please?

**Note:** the code above works if I type directly in mongodb access (`mongo shell`).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` and `sh` certain characters need escaping. You need to also use `"` and NOT `'`. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) for an answer as to what the difference is.

Within your script; `$ [ {` all need escaping with a `\` before them.

```
query="printjson(db.MYDATABASE.find( \$and: \[ \{ DATE:"2018" \}, \{ NAME:"TEST" \} \])"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I forgot to escape `[ ] { }`. But stiil not working after escape them. What can be now?

Comment: It returns me this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: `query='printjson(db.MYDATABASE.find(\{\$and:\[\{DATE:"2018"\},\{NAME:"TEST"\},\{\$or:\[\{CITY:"MYCITY"\},\{CITY:"ANOTHERCITY"\}\]\}\]\}));'`

Putting a SQL query for the same situation to you understand better what I'm trying to get: `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE DATE = "2018" AND NAME = "TEST" AND CITY IN ("MYCITY","CITY")`

Comment: @Rffonseca, sorry your comment is a little confusing! Did using `"` not help?

Comment: I find in web some codes including the `toArray()` function at end of expression and works (and without escaping)  :)

`query='printjson(db.MYDATABASE.find({$and:[{DATE:"2018"},{NAME:"TEST"},{$or:[{CITY:"MYCITY"},{CITY:"ANOTHERCITY"}]}]}).toArray());'`

But with this I just have one situation: it returns like the `pretty()` code, so print in json format. Have you any idea how I can print one result per line?